# Count all lines in the select statement, result value have column all the line number in select

Tags: sql, sql-server

![enter image description here][1]

I want in select  add a column "all line number" is all line was get(not use subquery).

Can use any data.

This my instance so everyone understands what are I need it.

```
select *, "all line number"
from SysUserInSubRoleRes
group by SubRoleId
having count(SubRoleId) > 2
order by SubRoleId desc
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 2  ROWS ONLY'

Value default:
SubRoleId
--------
  v1
  v2
  v3
  v1
  v2
  v2
  v1
  
Result Value 
add column alllinenumber

SubRoleID  |  AllLineNumber
  v1       |      3
  v2       |      3
```

Comment: Please show some sample data and expected results.

Comment: I presume `SysUserInSubRoleRes` has more columns than just `SubRoleId`, which means your `group by` is incomplete.

Comment: Table have columns, but I want show a column **SubRoleId**

Comment: You can see piture top

Comment: Best not to use images. Instead add data as formatted text.

Comment: @DaleK you run code

Comment: @Apple Yellow answer from Thiyagu should be close to what you require. If not why not?

Comment: @P.Salmon.  answer from Thiyagu, result value is number row, but i want result value have value of 'SubRoleId' and  number row  value of 'SubRoleId' insert in column 'All line muber'

Comment: Then include suberoleid in the select. And I'm not clear about 'all value of 'SubRoleId'' is that other than a count?

Comment: value of 'SubRoleId' is anything, It not number count

Answer (score 1):

Your expected output cannot be the result of your query since subroleid 1 has a alllinenumber 
= 1 and 2 as 2 neither of which pass the count test of > 2

You may be looking for something like

```
drop table t
go
create table t(subroleid int)
go
insert into t values (1),(2),(2),(2)

select subroleid, count(*) as "all line number"
from t
group by SubRoleId
having count(SubRoleId) > 2
order by SubRoleId desc

subroleid   all line number
----------- ---------------
2           3
```

but without sample data and expected output it's hard to be sure.

Edit 1.

```
drop table t
go
create table t(subroleid varchar(2))
go
insert into t values ('v1'),('v2'),('v3')


select t.subroleid,  cnt "all line number"
from t
cross join (select count(*) cnt from t) s
where cnt > 2
order by SubRoleId 
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 2  ROWS ONLY


subroleid all line number
--------- ---------------
v1        3
v2        3
```

Comment: I want alllinenumber = count(subroleid) and whole value of alllinenumber them same

Comment: There is no difference between count(subroleid)  and count(*) unless count(subroleid)  is supposed to be over the whole table. I am voting to close because you are not providing clarity via sample data.

Comment: You run code so see result value i need

Comment: Your last comment is just gibberish what code and what should I run it against?

Comment: I don't know how to understand what I mean

Comment: I additional condition. You can help me?

Comment: It seems you rows defined by the offset and fetch from your table together with a count across the whole tabel  but only if the count of subroleid across the whole table is greater than 2. Try the edit

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(SUBROLEID) AS [ALL LINE NUMBER]
FROM SYSUSERINSUBROLERES
GROUP BY SUBROLEID
HAVING COUNT(SUBROLEID) > 2
ORDER BY SUBROLEID DESC
```

Hope this Query Works for your case

Comment: Kinldy Provide Sample data and Expected Results -- @AppleYellow

Comment: I have Edited the Code now. can u check now @appleyellow

Comment: Possibly needs subroleid in select

Comment: Thanks, @Thiyagu help me

Answer (score 0):

If you want row number, then you can easily generate it

```sql
select SubRoleId, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SubRoleId DESC) AS [all line number]
from SysUserInSubRoleRes
group by SubRoleId
having count(SubRoleId) > 2
order by [all line number]
```